# is Chi square adapted for this case?

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a repartition on a categorical variables like this:
[image: histogram of categorical variables]

knowing a variable the repartition change like this:
[image: histogram of categorical variables]

I used a chi squared test:
[image]

and then obtain a result of 12.93, higher than the Q of the chi 2 table with 6 degrees of freedom and alpha=0.05 corresponding.

Can I say that I'm sure at 95% that there is a dependance between those 2 variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's absolutelly right! You've succesfully performed a $\chi^2$ test of independence! After seeing the plots, independence between the variables is hard to believe, and the test confirms that result. Also, as there are 2 variables and 7 categories for it, $1*6=6$ is the correct number of degrees of freedom